# How to add resources (e.g. a text file) in a Java Library for Android

Tags: java, android

I am creating a Java library for Android. Part of the library depends on a text file, which contains a large data set that can't be put inside a source code file.

Now It works when I'm testing locally but doesn't work when I'm trying to use it as a library.

I've got a feeling that it's not getting the path right or maybe the file itself is missing from the library.

I would like to know the steps to add a text file to a Java library for Android in Android Studio.

Do I've to add anything to the build file?
or do I've to put the text in a particular folder?
or do I've to use different code to get file path?
or something else.

I'm using https://jitpack.io for package repository.

For further infomation, you can have a look into the repository
https://github.com/lifeparticle/PhotonyLibs

### To get the data

```java
File file = new File("AstroJava/src/main/resources/cities.txt");
```

### Project Structure

```
── AstroJava.iml
├── README.md
├── build
│   ├── ******             
│   │                      
│   └── tmp
│       └── ******
├── build.gradle
├── libs
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── app
        │       └── photony
        │           └── java
        │               └── astrojava
        │                   ├── CalendarHelper.java
        │                   ├── Cities.java
        │                   ├── Main.java
        │                   ├── MathHelper.java
        │                   ├── Moon.java
        │                   ├── Sun.java
        │                   └── TimeZoneHelper.java
        └── resources
            └── cities.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can located the file into the "assets" folder.

```
── AstroJava.iml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        └── res
        └── assets
            └── cities.txt
```

And you can refer it in your code like:

#### Kotlin

```
val inputStream = context.assets.open("cities.txt")
```

#### Java

```java
try {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open("cities.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this is a Java library so I don't have the access to the context.assets.open("..") method or I'm missing something? @yoonhok

Comment: Oh... Sorry... this is not Android project, but pure java project... ignore my answer ;;;